# Get records from two unrelated tables together

Tags: mysql

I have a table of venues and services. I want to select all records from both tables at time. Both has different columns.

services table:

```
 Name   Type       Collation    Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    1   serviceId  Primary  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change 
    2   entry_by    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
    3   service_name    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
    4   service_address varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
    5   latitude    double          No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
    6   longitude   double          No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
    7   servicetypeId   int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop 
    8   active  int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop
```

venues table :

```
1   venueIdPrimary  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change 
2   venue_name  varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None    
3   venuetypeId int(11)         No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
4   entry_by    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
5   venue_address   varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
6   latitude    double          No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
7   longitude   double          No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   
8   active  int(11)
```

I tried this query : SELECT services.*,venues.* FROM `services`,`venues`

But it gives duplicate records. All records 3 times :

```
 1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
1
Halll siddhi
1
Abc
nasik
19.975409
73.841321
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
1
Halll siddhi
1
Abc
nasik
19.975409
73.841321
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
1
Halll siddhi
1
Abc
nasik
19.975409
73.841321
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
2
decorator siddhi
2
Abc
nasik
19.974781
73.854094
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
2
decorator siddhi
2
Abc
nasik
19.974781
73.854094
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
2
decorator siddhi
2
Abc
nasik
19.974781
73.854094
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
3
siddhi hall
8
sid17
nasik
19.995005
73.841308
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
3
siddhi hall
8
sid17
nasik
19.995005
73.841308
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
3
siddhi hall
8
sid17
nasik
19.995005
73.841308
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
4
siddhi hall
8
sid17
Sankuru, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-2.8437453
23.3823545
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
4
siddhi hall
8
sid17
Sankuru, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-2.8437453
23.3823545
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
4
siddhi hall
8
sid17
Sankuru, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-2.8437453
23.3823545
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
5
siddhi cafe
8
sid17
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
5
siddhi cafe
8
sid17
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
5
siddhi cafe
8
sid17
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
6
siddhi cafe
8
sid17
Lomami, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-1.899681
22.72851
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
6
siddhi cafe
8
sid17
Lomami, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-1.899681
22.72851
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
6
siddhi cafe
8
sid17
Lomami, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-1.899681
22.72851
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
7
green lawn
8
sid17
N5, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
7
green lawn
8
sid17
N5, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
7
green lawn
8
sid17
N5, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
1
1
Abc
DJ siddhi
nasik
1211
4545
1
1
8
hotel nashik
8
sid17
Mai-Ndombe, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-2.6357434
18.4276047
1
2
sid17
siddhi  cateror
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
0
0
6
1
8
hotel nashik
8
sid17
Mai-Ndombe, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-2.6357434
18.4276047
1
3
sid17
flowerist
Unnamed Road, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-10.4212157
28.6031842
6
1
8
hotel nashik
8
sid17
Mai-Ndombe, Democratic Republic of the Congo
-2.6357434
18.4276047
1
```

How can I get unique records from both tables? Thank you..

Comment: what sorta Expected Results shown in a Tabular Form by you are you looking for? [edit]

Comment: Try the DISTINCT keyword in your query.

Comment: both table dosn't have any relation, use " select * from table a union select * from table b"

Comment: tried union , it merges the venues records in services, I want records with different columns.@GoldunoSupport

Comment: I tried DISTINCT but dint work, @FDavidov

Comment: I want all records from both tables without duplicate records. @Drew

Comment: And there is no link of any kind between the two tables, right?

Comment: yes no link. @FDavidov

Comment: In that case, you may consider selecting from one table and then union the selection from the second table. When you select things from two tables together, you are implicitly JOINING the tables in the select and hence the duplications (specially when there are no conditions). With union, the duplicates (caused by the JOIN) are not created.

Comment: could you please suggest the query? @FDavidov

Comment: Which fields from each table you want to get in the result? (note that when UNION is used, the results of both selects need to be of the same TYPE)

Comment: I want to get all the fields from both tables.@FDavidov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 select 
 'Services'      as Source       ,
 serviceId       as ID           ,
 entry_by        as entry_by     ,
 service_name    as name         ,
 service_address as address      ,
 latitude        as latitude     ,
 longitude       as longitude    ,
 servicetypeId   as typeID       ,
 active          as active    
 from services

 union

 select
 'Venues'         as Source      ,
 venueIdPrimary   as ID          ,
 entry_by         as entry_by    ,
 venue_name       as name        ,
 venue_address    as address     ,
 latitude         as latitude    ,
 longitude        as longitude   ,
 venuetypeId      as typeID      ,
 active           as active    
 from venues ;
```

Note that I added a textual field so that you would know where the record is coming from.